# Multiple realms on Apache Shiro

Tags: java, hibernate, security, shiro

I have ‘n’ modules in my system, and each module has a specific group of users, differents roles, and a simple database.

I have a custom realm that queries  a main database. This database has a table with all users of my system. So, the query tells me if the user is registered, and which module the user should use.

So, when I get the user ‘s module name from database, I will access another realm, querying another database to set the permissions of my user.

The link (image) below show what I am trying to tell.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP0WX.png

I don’t know how can I make the relation between all realms. I’m trying to use ManagerRealm (extends of  ModularRealmAuthenticator),  but when I call assertRealmsConfigured() I get an exception saying that I don’t have realms configured.  I don’t know if the structure that I suggested is the best solution or which is the best way to do it. Can anyone help me?

Thanks  in Advance